# How to crop images from camera

Tags: android, image, android-camera, crop

How can I crop the camera images. Now it is showing the the image for crop and after selecting the crop section while tap on the "**Save**" button. Its showing as "**saving image**". After that nothing is happen. Here is my code.

**Button click :**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString());
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

**onActivityResult :**

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
if (bitmap != null) {
    Img_View.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use this code to perform cropping:

```
.....
final int CAMERA_CAPTURE = 1;
final int CROP_PIC = 2;
private Uri picUri;
....
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button captureBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.capture_btn);
        captureBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.capture_btn) {
            try {
                // use standard intent to capture an image
                Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                        MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                // we will handle the returned data in onActivityResult
                startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "This device doesn't support the crop action!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE) {
                // get the Uri for the captured image
                picUri = data.getData();
                performCrop();
            }
            // user is returning from cropping the image
            else if (requestCode == CROP_PIC) {
                // get the returned data
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                // get the cropped bitmap
                Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
                ImageView picView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture);
                picView.setImageBitmap(thePic);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * this function does the crop operation.
     */
    private void performCrop() {
        // take care of exceptions
        try {
            // call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not
            // support it)
            Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            // indicate image type and Uri
            cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
            // set crop properties
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            // indicate aspect of desired crop
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 2);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            // indicate output X and Y
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
            // retrieve data on return
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_PIC);
        }
        // respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            Toast toast = Toast
                    .makeText(this, "This device doesn't support the crop action!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

You can use following simple tutorial to perform cropping:

1. http://khurramitdeveloper.blogspot.in/2013/07/capture-or-select-from-gallery-and-crop.html
2. http://www.londatiga.net/featured-articles/how-to-select-and-crop-image-on-android/
3. http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/12/15/crop-image-android/
4. http://shaikhhamadali.blogspot.in/2013/09/capture-images-and-crop-images-using.html

Comment: This code works, just one question i need to save the image path, but does the cropped image allow this? and instead of a bitmap to show the image can the new uri be used?

Comment: I'm getting nullPointerException on this line. **Bundle extras = data.getExtras();**. extras is null. I'm using android M device.

Comment: doesn't work! because data.getData() is null after CAMERA_CAPTURE

Answer (score 6):

Save yourself a lot of time and use [this library](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) I was messing around with trying to do it myself and stumbled on this library and its really simple to use and you get a professional looking image cropping view that lets you choose camera or photo library.

Simple example:

Include the library in your gradle

```
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'
```

Add permissions to manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

//add this under <application>
<activity android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
  android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat"/>
```

In your activity

```
//on button press or anywhere, this starts the image picking and cropping process
CropImage.activity()
  .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
  .start(this);

//in your activity where you will get the result of your cropped image
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
    CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

      //From here you can load the image however you need to, I recommend using the Glide library

    } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
      Exception error = result.getError();
    }
  }
}
```

*Im not affiliated with this software*

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20062213)

Comment: @MaxVollmer ive added a simple example

Comment: @Fonix The library you have mentioned is excellent but sadly, it's not maintained any longer and uses deprecated functions. It would be great if you can suggest any other library you know of.

Comment: @James unfortunately not, as I haven't had to do anything with the camera in a while

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "tmp_avatar_"
                        + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        + ".jpg"));

                intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        mImageCaptureUri);

                intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);
                intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
                intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
                intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
                intent.putExtra("scale", true);
                intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
```