# How to add Crop Feature to Camera Intent or Gallery Intent & in Web-view?or In JavaScript

Tags: android, android-intent, webview, android-camera, crop

I followed [this](https://github.com/OpenGeeksMe/Android-File-Chooser/blob/master/app/src/main/java/it/floryn90/webapp/MainActivity.java) to Capture or Choose File from Web-view and Upload...This is perfect and working for all android versions..

So over there I want to Add Crop Intent... To crop After Camera Capturing/Gallery then Upload all this Happen From Webview

**I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35498670/5010291) intent to add for Crop Image.. I want to add this in MainActivity.. In Both Capture form Camera and Gallery**..

```
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
// indicate image type and Uri
cropIntent.setDataAndType(data.getData(), "image/*");
cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getTempUri());
cropIntent.putExtra("outputFormat",
        Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
// set crop properties
cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
// indicate aspect of desired crop
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
// indicate output X and Y
cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
// retrieve data on return
cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
// start the activity - we handle returning in
// onActivityResult
startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 3);
```

So It may Be camera or Gallery I want to Crop and Upload..

Can Any one suggest me How to add Crop Intent to Main activity..

**Update 1**

I Have a Intent to capture camera And View gallery.. In the similar way I have option for Crop Intent... But I want to apply this crop for Both camera intent and gallery but all these need to happen in webview(Mainactivity)...

Please Check my [Mainactivity](https://github.com/OpenGeeksMe/Android-File-Chooser/blob/master/app/src/main/java/it/floryn90/webapp/MainActivity.java)... Before answering..

I want to add Crop Intent fro camera intent and Gallery intent.. and it should able to upload... with min resolution... not more than 2megapixel.. if less than also no problem... like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35498004/how-to-use-camera-intent-with-crop-intent-both-at-one-intent-in-webview/35498670#35498670) at bitmap...

In update I have again added same links don't get confused...

All here It needs to crop and upload in webview...

**Update 2**

Is it possible use [this](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop) Library in my MainActivity... In case of camera capture from web-view crop and upload in same webview...

Comment: What problem are you facing? Is the above code not working?

Comment: Sir..I want to add CROP Intent In main activity can you suggest me where to add.. if possible add and Update Answer...

Comment: that means you are able to crop the image but unable to set it to webview, Right ?

Comment: No sir.. I am able to crop in separate application.. But not in webview mainactivity... with intents

Comment: Please don't down-vote without comment what will you get if u down-vote...

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one. Or, in your case, find some JavaScript-based image cropping library, and use that from your Web content.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare Sir ... If possible Please Make a Answer with example for JavaScript-based image cropping library.. I will add Bounty,,,,

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in simple way:

First capture the image using intent to camera,

```
 Intent intentCamera = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intentCamera, Constants.CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
```

In onActivityResult() you can capture the result whihc will return the url of the image captured.

Then you can intent for croping the image:

```
private void callCrop(Uri sourceImage) {
        CropImageIntentBuilder cropImage = new CropImageIntentBuilder(200, 200, getURL());
        cropImage.setOutlineColor(Color.WHITE);
        cropImage.setSourceImage(sourceImage);
        cropImage.setDoFaceDetection(false);
        startActivityForResult(cropImage.getIntent(this), Constants.CROP_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

You will get the croped image in again onActivityResult().

CropImageIntentBuilder source code is on github. Please find the link below

https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage/blob/master/CropImage/src/main/java/com/android/camera/CropImageIntentBuilder.java

UPDATE :

You can fire that intent of camera on some action like on click of button and I hope you will put you button in Activity.

```
camerBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent intentCamera = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intentCamera, Constants.CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
});


@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Bitmap saveBitmap = null;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == Constants.CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {

                if (data != null) {

                    Uri currentImageUri = data.getData();

                    if (currentImageUri != null) {
                        Bitmap currentBitmap = uriToBitmap(currentImageUri);
                        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(currentBitmap, 90); // Rotate bitmap by 90' to avoid the orientation change of image.
                        saveImageToFile(rotatedBitmap);  // save bitmap with rotation of 90' .
                        callCrop(getURL());
                    }

                } else {
                    return;
                }           
            } else if (requestCode == Constants.CROP_REQUEST_CODE) {
                saveBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getFile().getAbsolutePath());
                String convertedImage = Utils.bitMapToString(saveBitmap);                
            }        
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }



/**
     * To get Bitmap from respective Uri.
     *
     * @param selectedFileUri
     * @return bitmap
     */
    private Bitmap uriToBitmap(Uri selectedFileUri) {
        Bitmap image = null;
        try {
            ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
                    getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(selectedFileUri, "r");
            FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);


            parcelFileDescriptor.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return image;
    }

    /**
     * To rotate bitmap by an given angle(in degree).
     *
     * @param img    bitmap which you want to rotate.
     * @param degree
     * @return rotated bitmap.
     */
    private static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap img, int degree) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(degree);
        Bitmap rotatedImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        img.recycle();
        return rotatedImg;
    }
```

I hope it will make more sense to you now.

Comment: I m editing my answer to make it more meaningful for you.