# image not cropping after cropped

Tags: android, image, android-intent

I am attempting to crop an image using intent after the image is selected from the gallery. Here is my snippet of code

```
private void showFileChooser() {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        //******code for crop image
        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }
```

Here I am calling the above snippet with PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST intent handle

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            try {
                Uri filePath = data.getData();
```

what could be wrong since I am using the same intent after cropping which is PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST

Comment: what is the problem? What is not working?

Comment: Do you select the image, but it return the full image instead of oppening a crop screen?

Comment: You are correct but after cropping it sets the full image to imageView instead of the cropped version at Eduardo Herzer

Comment: Well... then CommonsWare answer is right. There is no native support or documented extras for cropping an image. Two options: 1) You should use a library as pointed in answer; 2) If it is not a requirement, you could check if the device supports crop action: if it doesn't, use full image; if it does, use the crop intent (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26358351/2174489 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/39633047/2174489 should help in this case)

Answer (score 0):

There are no documented and supported "crop" extras for `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or any other standard Android `Intent`. Nor is there a documented and supported standard `Intent` action for cropping. There is no requirement for any device to have apps that support undocumented and unsupported extras, actions, etc.

If you want to crop an image, use any one of [a number of existing open source libraries for image cropping](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45).