# camera button is working but i am unable to perform cropping

Tags: java, android, crop

**When i press the button then the camera captures the picture, I want to perform crop on that picture after Cropping but i am unable to figure out the problem because crop function is not working properly, Please Help me to figure out the problem that is the main cause of crop function is not being preformed**

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
        final int CAMERA_CAPTURE = 1;
        final int CROP_PIC = 2;
        private Uri picUri;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Button captureBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.capture_btn);
            captureBtn.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.capture_btn) {
                try {
                    // use standard intent to capture an image
                    Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                            MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    // we will handle the returned data in onActivityResult
                    startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "This device doesn't support the crop action!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }

        }

        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            Toast toast4 = Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(RESULT_OK),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast4.show();

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "capture ok",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE) {
                    // get the Uri for the captured image
                    picUri = data.getData();
    //                Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(requestCode),
    //                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    //                toast1.show();
                    performCrop();
                }
                // user is returning from cropping the image
                if (requestCode == CROP_PIC) {
                    Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(this, "crop ok",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast1.show();
                    // get the returned data
                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                    // get the cropped bitmap
                    Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
                    ImageView picView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture);
                    picView.setImageBitmap(thePic);
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * this function does the crop operation.
         */

        private void performCrop() {
    ////////////////// take care of exceptions

            try {
                // call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not
                // support it)
                Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
                // indicate image type and Uri
                cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
                // set crop properties
                cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                // indicate aspect of desired crop
                cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
                // indicate output X and Y
                cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
                cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
                // retrieve data on return
                cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
                startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_PIC);
                }
                 catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                Toast toast3 = Toast
                        .makeText(this, "This device doesn't support the crop action!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast3.show();
            }

            }

        }
```

Comment: `com.android.camera.action.CROP` is not mandatory for Android, it is optional. You should not expect that device supports it.

Comment: See: https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357012/how-to-crop-images-from-camera) is what you are looking for.

Comment: what should i used instead of com.android.camera.action.Crop because i have tried my best to resolve this issue

Comment: use your own implemented cropping. Or at least search for the library.